# PHP: invalid string not letting me compare it correctly

Tags: php, imap

A really weird string is being produced inside an array for some reason, and I don't know how to treat it... I am getting the string and outputting it with the following code:

```
    $server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
    $connection = imap_open($server, 'myuser', 'mypass');
    $count = imap_num_msg($connection); 
    $header = imap_headerinfo($connection, $i); 
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) { 
        $from = $header['fromaddress'];
        var_dump($from);
   }
```

And this is the result I get from that var_dump:

```
string(39) "Support Testing1"
```

How is that possible? And is there any way I can convert that to the correct string (I mean, with the right length?)

This is affecting my code, because now:

```
echo ('Support Testing1' == $from)
```

gives me false, when it should be true. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update:** trim is not working either.

Comment: Does `trim($header['fromaddress']) == $header['fromaddress']` ?

Comment: Can you give a little more from your code?

Comment: What is the context of this issue? Looks like it's related to a php mail script?

Comment: trim is not working... I updated the code with more info! Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't 'from' be an email address? It looks to be an email alias.

Comment: What's with the closing parenthesis after `$header['fromaddress']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that `$header['fromaddress']` is really something like

```
"Support Testing1" <blah@example.com>
```

And you don't see the email address in the var dump because the browser treats it like an HTML tag.

If this is so, then you need to remove the `<...>`, and probably the double quotes as well.

You can try viewing the source HTML to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$from = trim($header['fromaddress']));
```

There may be hidden whitespace characters on either end.

Answer (score 0):

A wrong length is probably a matter of encoding !

Try :

```
var_dump( utf8_decode( $header['fromaddress'] ) );
```